# Hide a block in an override xml that doesn't have a name?

Tags: layout, override-block

I have the following block that is added in a 3rd party SSO module.  I'm overriding part of the module, and I want to hide this block.

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Company\WebSSO\Block\LoginButton" ifconfig="company/websso/enabled_frontend" template="Company_WebSSO::default/button.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

I know how to use `remove="true"` in my xml override, but usually it requires that the block have a name, or be in its own container.  I don't have this luxury.  Is there another way to hide / delete the block from the layout?

Comment: Well, you know how to override a module so rewrite the block to return nothing in a its ```_prepareLayout``` for example, or build an observer after render to remove the block by its instance ```Company\WebSSO\Block\LoginButton```.

Comment: Thats what I figured. What a pain.

Comment: Haha, come ooon, go edit the layout and give it a name :p I will not snitch. We will also edit the post and our comments and no one will know.

Comment: You have no idea how close I am to doing this.

Comment: Well, it's not that bad to give it a name. You could even do it in your theme only if you wish to update the module.

Comment: It has been named.  We've already hacked up the module and I'm tired of being academic about it.  Thanks for the inspiration.

Comment: Final advice : leave a not tohl your layout update in case anyone (even you, I forget things all the time) updates the module.